# Object Manager returnig wrong data in template file Magento 2.3.3

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework, magento2

I know that using object manager in Magento 2 templates is not recommended but for some test purpose I need to use it, I need to get current cart data in the list.phtml and I am using the below code

```
$objmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session =  $objmanager->get("Magento\Checkout\Model\Session");
$quote = $session->getQuote();
$qty =  $quote->getItemsSummaryQty();
print_r($quote->getData());
```

In my cart I have 2 products but the response form the above code returns the below

```
 Array ( [is_checkout_cart] => 1 [store_id] => 1 [remote_ip] => ::1 [x_forwarded_for] => [all_items_qty] => 0 )
```

What am I missing or need to be corrected?

Comment: you want to get cart details am I right?

Comment: in my observer i am able to get the cart items details

$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
  $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

but in templates i am unable to get this data.

Comment: I think in template you used  $objmanager->get("Magento\Checkout\Model\Session"); not this $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')

Comment: i tried this also but it is not working for some reson

Comment: try this $om =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cartData = $om->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

Comment: have you try it?